# How can I get email notification when new user was created in the Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In which way could be configured Azure Cloud to have possibility sent an email notification when a user was created or removed from Azure Active Directory

Comment: Azure Event Grid will get support for certain events from Azure AD in the future, no specific dates for when those will be available though. That one might help you implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in, generic feature for sending emails to user when user is added or removed in Azure AD. You may leave your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory). All the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.